# waiting for another class output result

Tags: java, android

After the user press login button, login class will sent the information to another class(backgroundworker) to verify the login information. backgroundworker will communicate to server and then return the result.
Currently I sleep the thread 2 second to make sure that it have enough time to communicate server. 
Does there have any method that login class to detect backgroundworker get the result? So that I can prevent to hard-code the sleep time.

login:

```
public void OnLogin(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    final String email = emailEt.getText().toString();
    final String type = "login";
    final BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(backgroundWorker.getResult().equals("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">login success")){
                SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("mceDiscussBoard", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                editor.putString("email",email);
                editor.commit();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RoomActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }else{
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Loading......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            backgroundWorker.execute(type, email);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Try to sleep for roughly 2 seconds
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

backgroundworker:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>  {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
int singal=0;
String result="";
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://www.xxx.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String email = params[1];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit misplaced to me.  Typically, the async should be the one who decides what to do upon logic failure or success.  For example, you might advance to another activity on success, or display an error message upon failure.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is another thread that runs concurrently to main thread. Methods `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` should be used to run code before and after `doInBackground`. While background thread is running you can show progress bar to the user